# PHP Add number to variable from array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have this code:

```
if( ( $cacheout - $data['import_time'] ) > 129600 ){
                unset( $fresh_data[$key] );
}
```

$data gets the time (import time) from an array which is a digital value, for example: 1576784091.

I wanted to add 43200 to this $data['import_time'] variable.

How to save it?

Comment: Show the part of `$data` array. And desired output.

Comment: Do you want to add `$data['import_time'] + 43200` or swith import_time to  43200 ?

Comment: I want to add 43200, not switch

Comment: This is incredibly basic programming, are we missing something? You do it the same way you add to any other variable, there's nothing special about arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```
$data['import_time'] += 43200;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use `+=`?

Comment: Why not both versions?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
$data['import_time'] = $data['import_time'] + 43200;
```